# Animate UIView from circle to pin

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-animation, cashapelayer

I need to implement an animation where I start from circle into a pin.
The animation will start when I long press the circle, the circle will become a pin. When I release the view the pin will return to it's initial form (circle)

At the end it will look like:
[image]

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a bit complex, you need to implemenment shape morphing animation using two set of `UIBezierPath`.

#### Create two bezier paths first to define the shapes for circle and pin

1. First prepare a `UIBezierPath` which defines the `pin`. You may need to have several call to `addQuadCurve(to endPoint: CGPoint, controlPoint: CGPoint)` to achive the perfect shape. Let's say this `UIBezierPath` as `pinPath`,
2. In second step, you need to create another shape for the `circle` just by moving the points or changing the curves used in creating bezier path for the `pin`. Make sure the number of points/curves will be exactly same in both paths, the change will be in poisitions or control points. Let's call this bezier paths as `circlePath`.

[YOU MAY NEED TO WORK WITH YOUR DESIGNER CLOSELY TO CREATE THESE TWO SHAPES, you can export these shapes as SVG files and conver them to `UIBezierPath` using http://svg-converter.kyome.io/]

#### Add your shape on custom `UIControl` which will act as slider.

Let's say your thumb layer is called as `thumbLayer`.

```
let thumbLayer = CAShapeLayer()
thumbLayer.frame = ...
thumbLayer.fillColor = ...
thumbLayer.strokeColor = ...
thumbLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
myCustomSlider.layer.addSublayer(thumbLayer)
```

#### Animate from Circle to Pin shape

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
animation.toValue = pinPath.cgPath
animation.duration = 1
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
thumbLayer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
```

I hope this [example gist](https://gist.github.com/AliSoftware/a7be50178f1106e51de382b1bf975c5b) will be helpful for you to understand the basic idea of shape morphing animation using `UIBezierPath`.

[image]